# Error: network interface must be attached to a supported instance - CreateTraffic Mirror Session

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mirroring, network-interface, network-security

I am trying to create a mirroring session from one ec2 instance in a public subnet ( the mirroring source) to another instance in a private subnet ( the mirroring target)

When I tried to create the session and select the source network interface, I get an error that the selected network interface must be attached to a supported instance

The interface is a primary interface ant its attachment status is attached

I tried to create another interface and attache it manually then I used the interface for the mirroring session but I got the same error

[image: the error message is " eni-X must be attached to a supported instance"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by changing the instance type to a nitro-based instance. 
see the following instance types

[enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#ec2-nitro-instances)